# @vue-cli install error, Can't install vue-cli

Tags: node.js, vue.js

```
$ npm i -g @vue/cli
npm WARN deprecated hoek@5.0.4: This version is no longer maintained.Please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.5: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead
/Users/terryakishin/.npm-global/bin/vue -> /Users/terryakishin/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js
+ @vue/cli@3.2.1
updated 3 packages in 37.486s


$ vue --version
-bash: vue: command not found

$ vue create front
-bash: vue: command not found
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Please answer me why it didn't work. As soon as updating the MacOS, vue.js didn't work.

```
$ node -v
v8.11.3
$ npm -v
5.6.0
```

Comment: Not sure if it'll help, but 8.11.3 is a pretty old version, have you considered upgrading node?

Comment: Looks like `~/.npm-global/bin` isn't in your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: @Paul
Thank you Paul. but it's not solution in that case.

Comment: @ Phil
Thank you Phil. but I don't understand what you mean. According to what you said to me, you told me to change the path, but I didn't know how to change.
Please more detail.